# Incrustar PDF con Django

Tags: django

Buenas tardes en mi aplicación los usuarios pueden subir archivos PDF, cuya ruta queda almacenada en el modelo de usuario. Ahora bien mi pregunta es que plugin me recomiendan para poder incrustar y visualizar estos archivos PDF en un template.

He estado intendando con Google Docs Lector pero me ha dado lios la URL ya que es un sitio local

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=AQUÍ URL PDF O DOCUMENTO&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;">  </iframe>
```

Agradezco su colaboración

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba usar el siguiente código, a mí me funciona usando archivos locales y archivos en línea:

```
<embed id='pdf' src="nombredelpdf.pdf"></embed>
```

La etiqueta `<embed/>` es HTML5. Como es estándar debería de funcionar en todos los navegadores con soporte HTML5 y PDF, y con archivos locales y externos.

Más información sobre `embed` en la [especificación de W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-embed-element) (texto en inglés).

Comment: Esto puede solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, pero necesita algo más de información: ¿por qué lo solucionaría? ¿Qué diferencias hay con lo que ya tiene el usuario?

Comment: Edite la respuesta, el codigo embed es lo que usa ahora y fue creado para ello, hay varias manerass de solucionar el problema pero embed es la correcta. Y funciona con archivos locales y externos.

Comment: Muy sencilla y efectiva a solución. Para los que usamos Django la solución fue la siguiente: <embed src="/{{ hogar.recibo }}" style="width:900px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"> </embed>

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo el libro Django By Example, donde se trabaja con 
la librería WeasyPrint y ponen ejemplos prácticos. Nota está en inglés. Otra libreria es Reportlab busca la documentación oficial http://www.reportlab.com/. saludos